# Android ksoap2 handle ASP.NET exception

Tags: android, asp.net, exception, ksoap2

I have an ASP.NET `WebService` which will throw exception if the input condition is wrong.

If it is invoked by another C# / ASP.NET application client, they can interpret the exception correctly.

But if it is invoked by ksoap2, I will get a HTTP Status 500 instead.

May I know what is the best way for me to handle this exception, and most importantly retrieve the error message within that exception, so that I can display to the user.

Thanks in advance.

---- Adding the code below:

## ASP.NET Web Services

```
[WebMethod]
public void Test()
{
    throw new Exception("This is a test message");
}
```

## Android ksoap2 client

```
// There are some details been obmitted. Just assume the code below works ok?

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 60000);
try
{
    // The Web Service in ASPNET is invoked successfully. And an Exception is thrown.
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    SoapObject obj;
    obj = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Manage to reach here. But How can I retrieve the Fault Message "This is a test message"?
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It basically is `response code` . You may check whether it is `404,500,403` etc. and based on that you may show a toast or something.

Comment: Yes, I only get the Response Code 505. But the fact is, the SOAP fault comes with a message. An ASPNET client will be able to retrieve that particular message. But ksoap2 client doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using version 3.0.0 of ksoap2-android and you received a SOAP fault in the response with a corresponding HTTP 500 error code you would not have received the SOAP fault object.

This has been fixed in version 3.0.1: https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/ProjectNews.